# "Unhandled stream error in pipe" - Too many file downloads in Node.js / request?

Tags: node.js, request

I am trying to download many (around 2,000) images from a JSON feed using Node,  (and specifically the request module).  When I try to do this (looping through the JSON) I get

`throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.`

I checked `ulimit -n` and it was set at 256, so I increased that to 4,000 and I still get the same error (although after I am downloading a much higher number of images).

I have two questions,

1. Why am I still getting an error if I raised the maximum download number well in excess of the number of simultaneous downloads I actually have
2. What is the best way to "queue" or pause the downloads so as not to overwhelm my system?  Here is my code.

`var fs = require('fs')
    , http = require('http')
    , request = require('request')
    , url = 'http://www.urlOfJsonFeed'`

```
function get(){
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {    
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            jParse(body);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
          console.log("Got error: ", e);
    });
}

function jParse(info){
    data = JSON.parse(info)
    entries = data.entries
    numToDownload = entries.length;     
    for(var i = numToDownload - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1){
        link = entries[i]['imgUrl']
        download(link, 'images/' + mov + '.mp4', function(){
            console.log('Downloaded  ' + dMov + ' movies')
            dMov++
        }
    }
}


var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    if (err) {
        console.log('header error');
    }
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        //Download the image
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    }
  });
};

get()
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I actually forgot about this problem, and did not solve it.  I do not think it would be too challenging though.  One approach would be to use promises and set a download queue of 300 or so.

Comment: Thanks for replying Startec. I managed to solve my problem after writing the comment yesterday. I noticed that I didn't close the stream after the file was finished. I haven't tested with more than ~500 files but I don't think I need to queue the downloads. Example: let file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath).on('finish', () => { file.end(); });